# How to do rotation animation on a RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, android-animation, nineoldandroids

I need to do a rotate animation on a `RelativeLayout`, I've used `NineOldAndroid` library for animation:

```
View v = findViewById(R.id.wrap_btnSelect);
ObjectAnimator t1 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(
        v, "rotation", 0.0f, -45.0f);
t1.setStartDelay(500);
t1.setDuration(1500);
t1.start();
```

The animation works fine, also click posions are updated accordingly on `ICS`, but on `Gingerbread` click positions stays at old position which makes view un-clickable.

is there anything i can do to fix this issue on android 2.3 ?

Original Layout:

[image: Original Layout]

Trying to achieve this:

[image: Rotated Layout]

EDIT: This layout is constructed of 4 squares, each is a `TextView`.

Answer (score 1):

You can extend `View` to handle touch events yourself, and tell in which area you are clicking, depending on your value of rotation at the moment of the click.

Something like this:

```
public class WrapBtnSelect extends RelativeLayout {
    // Copy onstructors here

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            double x = (event.getX() / getWidth()) * 2 - 1;
            double y = (event.getY() / getHeight()) * 2 - 1;
            double angle = Math.atan2(y, x);
            // Do your actions depending on the angle here

            return true;
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

Comment: This layout is constructed of 4 squares, each is a `TextView`. this method seems to be somehow overwork. is it possible to actually rotate buttons ?

Comment: You can call `View.setRotation()` on your `RelativeLayout` but it's only available from API 11 (BTW you're also using `ObjectAnimator` which is only available from API 11). To work from API 8 I would animate the `RelativeLayout` with a View Animation, and use the custom class to handle click events, because View Animation doesn't actually move the view, so your position won't update depending on the animation.